# Arcpy.python ArcServer sde permissions

Tags: python, permissions, arcpy

I have this python script that basically selects a point by it's ID, then selects all points within a distance and returns only a subset of those that match the type field.  i.e. find all hospitals within 3 miles of this location..

My python script works, does what it's supposed to. So I create a GP service from it. Add the service back into the map and run it. Now I notice no matter what distance I use, the data doesn't change. If I delete the created Featureclass to see if it's really working. It does not create a new featureclass but it says it completed successfully.

Now the weird part, if I hit the GP service at the rest endpoint with the parameters it says it works but returns no records. I've been careful to avoid schema locks when using the Rest endpoint ArcMap and ArcCatalog are closed.

It's like the GP service doesn't have permission to write to the sde database, However my sde connection works fine on my PC.

Any ideas?

```
import arcpy, os, string
from arcpy import env

db = r"Connection to racdev1.sde" 
theworkspace = r"Connection to racdev1.sde" 
arcpy.env.workspace = theworkspace

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#facilityID = '1249'
facilityID = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
#facilityIDType= 'PFI'
facilityIDType = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

thedistance = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
#thedistance = '3 miles'
#withindistance = "3 Miles"
withindistance =  thedistance + ' Miles'

sql_query = "\"%s\" = '%s'" % ("ID", facilityID)           
sql_query2 = "\"%s\" = '%s'" % ("IDTYPE", facilityIDType)

# Local variables:
Facilities = "DOHGIS.NYSDOH_CI_DATA"
featLayer = "thePts"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Facilities, featLayer)

# Process: Select Layer By Attribute
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(featLayer, "NEW_SELECTION", sql_query)

# Process: Select Layer By Location  311
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(featLayer, "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE",featLayer, withindistance, "NEW_SELECTION")

#print " now for the subset"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("thePts", "SUBSET_SELECTION", sql_query2  )

# creaate the new featureclss.. 
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("thePts",'DOHGIS.NYSDOH_FacilitiesQuery')
#print "Done"
```

Comment: How are you connecting to the SDE in your script? If you're using connection files, I've found these to be so flaky that they are useless with ArcGIS 10.2. However, I've had success using the Python window in ArcMap during a versioned edit session. Another idea would be to write to the database directly (e.g. using cx_Oracle for an Oracle database) if you have the privileges for that.

Comment: Just in case you are not aware of it there is a [gis.se] Stack Exchange with MANY ArcPy questions already answered on it.